# Join query taking 11 mins to run on 300,000 rows table

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

Below query is taking more than 11 minutes to execute.

```
SELECT `c`.*, 
       `e`.`name`                                                 AS `employee_name`, 
       `e`.`emp_no`, 
       `d`.`code`                                                 AS `department_code`, 
       IF(ew.code IS NOT NULL, ew.code, egw.code)                 AS shift_code, 
       IF(ew.code IS NOT NULL, ew.time_in_from, egw.time_in_from) AS time_in_from, 
       IF(ew.code IS NOT NULL, ew.time_out_to, egw.time_out_to)   AS time_out_to, 
       IF(ew.code IS NOT NULL, ew.next_day, egw.next_day)         AS next_day 
FROM   `tms_emp_badge_card` AS `c` 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_door_record_raw` AS `dr` 
              ON `c`.`card_no` = `dr`.`card_no` 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_employee` AS `e` 
              ON `c`.`emp_no` = `e`.`emp_no` 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_emp_group` AS `g` 
              ON `e`.`group_id` = `g`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_emp_department` AS `d` 
              ON `e`.`department_id` = `d`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_emp_workschedule` AS `ewt` 
              ON `ewt`.`workschedule_date` = "2016-11-01" 
                 AND ( ewt.reference_no = c.emp_no 
                       AND ewt.reference_type = "emp_no" ) 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_workschedule` AS `ew` 
              ON `ewt`.`workschedule_id` = `ew`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_emp_workschedule` AS `egwt` 
              ON `egwt`.`workschedule_date` = "2016-11-01" 
                 AND ( egwt.reference_no = g.code 
                       AND egwt.reference_type = "group_code" ) 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_workschedule` AS `egw` 
              ON `egwt`.`workschedule_id` = `egw`.`id` 
WHERE  `dr`.`record_time` BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2016-11-02' 
GROUP  BY `c`.`card_no` 
ORDER  BY c.emp_no
```

Below is the explain query

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                           | key                                     | key_len | ref                      | rows | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | ALL    | tms_emp_badge_card_card_no_index,emp_card_no                            | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL                     |  884 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | NULL       | eq_ref | tms_employee_emp_no_unique                                              | tms_employee_emp_no_unique              | 767     | tms.c.emp_no             |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | g     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                 | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | tms.e.group_id           |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                 | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | tms.e.department_id      |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dr    | NULL       | ref    | tms_door_record_raw_card_no_index,tms_door_record_raw_record_time_index | tms_door_record_raw_card_no_index       | 767     | tms.c.card_no            |  276 |     1.27 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ewt   | NULL       | ref    | tms_emp_workschedule_reference_no_index,workschedule_date               | tms_emp_workschedule_reference_no_index | 767     | tms.c.emp_no             |   83 |   100.00 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ew    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                 | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | tms.ewt.workschedule_id  |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | egwt  | NULL       | ref    | tms_emp_workschedule_reference_no_index,workschedule_date               | tms_emp_workschedule_reference_no_index | 767     | tms.g.code               |   83 |   100.00 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | egw   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                 | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | tms.egwt.workschedule_id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `tms_emp_badge_card` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `import_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `card_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tms_emp_badge_card_import_id_unique` (`import_id`),
  KEY `tms_emp_badge_card_emp_no_index` (`emp_no`),
  KEY `tms_emp_badge_card_card_no_index` (`card_no`),
  KEY `emp_card_no` (`card_no`,`emp_no`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=885 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci


CREATE TABLE `tms_door_record_raw` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `import_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `door_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `controller_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `record_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `record_state` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `open_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pass_flag` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hand_value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lfeet_value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rfeet_value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tms_door_record_raw_import_id_unique` (`import_id`),
  KEY `tms_door_record_raw_card_no_index` (`card_no`),
  KEY `tms_door_record_raw_door_no_index` (`door_no`),
  KEY `tms_door_record_raw_controller_no_index` (`controller_no`),
  KEY `tms_door_record_raw_record_time_index` (`record_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=368713 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci


 CREATE TABLE `tms_employee` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `import_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `plant_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `department_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `attendance_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tms_employee_emp_no_unique` (`emp_no`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tms_employee_import_id_unique` (`import_id`),
  KEY `tms_employee_plant_id_foreign` (`plant_id`),
  KEY `tms_employee_department_id_foreign` (`department_id`),
  KEY `tms_employee_group_id_foreign` (`group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tms_employee_department_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `tms_emp_department` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `tms_employee_group_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `tms_emp_group` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `tms_employee_plant_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`plant_id`) REFERENCES `tms_emp_plant` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=865 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

p_no`, 
       `d (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `import_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tms_emp_group_import_id_unique` (`import_id`),
  KEY `tms_emp_group_code_index` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `tms_emp_department` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `import_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tms_emp_department_import_id_unique` (`import_id`),
  KEY `tms_emp_department_code_index` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=82 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `tms_emp_workschedule` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `import_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference_type` enum('emp_no','plant_code','department_code','group_code') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reference_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `workschedule_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `workschedule_date` date NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tms_emp_workschedule_import_id_unique` (`import_id`),
  KEY `tms_emp_workschedule_reference_no_index` (`reference_no`),
  KEY `tms_emp_workschedule_workschedule_id_foreign` (`workschedule_id`),
  KEY `workschedule_date` (`workschedule_date`),
  CONSTRAINT `tms_emp_workschedule_workschedule_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`workschedule_id`) REFERENCES `tms_workschedule` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27597 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `tms_workschedule` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `import_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `time_in` time NOT NULL,
  `time_in_from` time NOT NULL,
  `time_in_to` time NOT NULL,
  `time_out` time NOT NULL,
  `time_out_from` time NOT NULL,
  `time_out_to` time NOT NULL,
  `next_day` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tms_workschedule_import_id_unique` (`import_id`),
  KEY `tms_workschedule_code_index` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I am thinking whether is the "Using temporary; Using filesort problem", or I should create multi column index but I don't know how to fix it. Please advise.

---

**Update 1:**

After adding multi column index on tms_door_record_raw table (KEY `card_no_record_time` (`card_no`,`record_time`)) The sql execution went down from 11mins to 3.2 seconds

Execute the explain sql again. The join table key for `dr` has change from (card_no) to (card_no, record_time) also on the extra column it is showing `Using where; Using index`

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                               | key                                     | key_len | ref                      | rows | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | ALL    | tms_emp_badge_card_card_no_index,emp_card_no                                                | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL                     |  884 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | NULL       | eq_ref | tms_employee_emp_no_unique                                                                  | tms_employee_emp_no_unique              | 767     | tms.c.emp_no             |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | g     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                     | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | tms.e.group_id           |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                     | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | tms.e.department_id      |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
| *1 | SIMPLE      | dr    | NULL       | ref    | tms_door_record_raw_card_no_index,tms_door_record_raw_record_time_index,record_time_card_no | record_time_card_no                     | 767     | tms.c.card_no            |  266 |     1.27 | Using where; Using index        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ewt   | NULL       | ref    | tms_emp_workschedule_reference_no_index,workschedule_date                                   | tms_emp_workschedule_reference_no_index | 767     | tms.c.emp_no             |   83 |   100.00 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ew    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                     | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | tms.ewt.workschedule_id  |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | egwt  | NULL       | ref    | tms_emp_workschedule_reference_no_index,workschedule_date                                   | tms_emp_workschedule_reference_no_index | 767     | tms.g.code               |   83 |   100.00 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | egw   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                     | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | tms.egwt.workschedule_id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

**Update 2:**
Remove the `dr` join sql and replace by where exist condition suggested by @mendosi change the execution time to 0.60 seconds.

```
SELECT `c`.*, 
       `e`.`name`                                                 AS `employee_name`, 
       `e`.`emp_no`, 
       `d`.`code`                                                 AS `department_code`, 
       IF(ew.code IS NOT NULL, ew.code, egw.code)                 AS shift_code, 
       IF(ew.code IS NOT NULL, ew.time_in_from, egw.time_in_from) AS time_in_from, 
       IF(ew.code IS NOT NULL, ew.time_out_to, egw.time_out_to)   AS time_out_to, 
       IF(ew.code IS NOT NULL, ew.next_day, egw.next_day)         AS next_day 
FROM   `tms_emp_badge_card` AS `c`  
       LEFT JOIN `tms_employee` AS `e` 
              ON `c`.`emp_no` = `e`.`emp_no` 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_emp_group` AS `g` 
              ON `e`.`group_id` = `g`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_emp_department` AS `d` 
              ON `e`.`department_id` = `d`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_emp_workschedule` AS `ewt` 
              ON `ewt`.`workschedule_date` = "2016-11-01" 
                 AND ( ewt.reference_no = c.emp_no 
                       AND ewt.reference_type = "emp_no" ) 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_workschedule` AS `ew` 
              ON `ewt`.`workschedule_id` = `ew`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_emp_workschedule` AS `egwt` 
              ON `egwt`.`workschedule_date` = "2016-11-01" 
                 AND ( egwt.reference_no = g.code 
                       AND egwt.reference_type = "group_code" ) 
       LEFT JOIN `tms_workschedule` AS `egw` 
              ON `egwt`.`workschedule_id` = `egw`.`id` 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tms_door_record_raw As dr WHERE c.card_no = dr.card_no AND dr.record_time BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2016-11-02') 
ORDER BY c.emp_no;
```

Below is the explain sql

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                               | key                                     | key_len | ref                      | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | c     | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                        | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL                     |  884 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | e     | NULL       | eq_ref | tms_employee_emp_no_unique                                                                  | tms_employee_emp_no_unique              | 767     | tms.c.emp_no             |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | g     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                     | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | tms.e.group_id           |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | d     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                     | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | tms.e.department_id      |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | ewt   | NULL       | ref    | tms_emp_workschedule_reference_no_index,workschedule_date                                   | tms_emp_workschedule_reference_no_index | 767     | tms.c.emp_no             |   83 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | ew    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                     | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | tms.ewt.workschedule_id  |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | egwt  | NULL       | ref    | tms_emp_workschedule_reference_no_index,workschedule_date                                   | tms_emp_workschedule_reference_no_index | 767     | tms.g.code               |   83 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | egw   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                     | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | tms.egwt.workschedule_id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | dr    | NULL       | ref    | tms_door_record_raw_card_no_index,tms_door_record_raw_record_time_index,record_time_card_no | record_time_card_no                     | 767     | tms.c.card_no            |  266 |     1.27 | Using where; Using index |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Are all `LEFT JOIN:s` necessary or can some of them be replaced with `INNER JOIN:s`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should help with the execution time:

- remove the `ORDER BY` if it isn't strictly necessary
- replace the join of `dr` table with `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tms_door_record_raw As dr WHERE c.card_no = dr.card_no AND dr.record_time BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2016-11-02')`
- `GROUP BY`, may now not be needed
- widen the index on `tms_door_record_raw` to include both `card_no` and `record_time`

Test this and see if progress is being made. Further steps may be necessary but hopefully this is in the right direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49415/discussion-between-cww-and-mendosi).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the GROUP BY.
If you have (logicaly valid) duplicates remove them at early stage.

Comment: sure, i will update you again on the sql execution time once I remove the index from current table. 

However I couldn't remove the group by c.card_no, due to `tms_door_record_raw` table have multiple record with single card no. example, card 0001 have few in/out records in 1 day, so it will show multiple record where I only need if the card having record in that day.

Comment: Thank you. I suggest trying to the aggregation on tms_door_record_raw before the joins.